# Modify CriteriaQuery JOINs after they have been added to the CriteriaQuery

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, criteria, criteria-api

Currently, I have a `UserDao` class which creates a query using `CriteriaQuery`, for example to retrieve an instance of `User` from the database using its ID (let's call that method `findById`). So far, it's pretty straightforward and that works fine.

However, I also have a `GenericDao`, which is extended by `UserDao`. Before `userDao.findById` returns its results, it passes the `criteriaQuery` to the `GenericDao` so I can add some restrictions to the `criteriaQuery`.

Example:

```
public class GenericDao
{
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    protected Object executeCriteriaQuery(CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery)
    {
        return entityManager.createQuery(prepareQuery(criteriaQuery)).getSingleResult();
    }

    private CriteriaQuery prepareQuery(CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery)
    {
        // add restrictions to criteriaQuery
        Predicate predicate = ... // some predicate which will be appended to the already formed criteriaQuery

        criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaQuery.getRestriction(), predicate));

        return criteriaQuery;
    }
}

public class UserDao extends GenericDao
{
    public User findById(String id)
    {
        CriteriaQuery query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(entityClass);
        Root<P> entity = query.from(entityClass);
        query.select(entity);
        query.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(entity.get("id"), id.toUpperCase()));

        return executeCriteriaQuery(query);
    }
}
```

The thing is: the query that is built in the DAOs that extend my `GenericDao` may contain a `JOIN`. I want to add a predicate to a `JOIN` that is added to the `criteriaQuery`.
From what I can see, I can retrieve the `JOIN`s in the query by using [From.getJoins()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/From.html#getJoins%28%29). However, according to the Javadoc for that method:

> Return the joins that have been made from this bound type. Returns empty set if no joins have been made from this bound type. **Modifications to the set do not affect the query.**
>
> Returns: joins made from this type

How can I add a predicate to `JOIN` clauses in my `criteriaQuery`?

Comment: What prevents you from build/modify criteria queries in concrete DAO classes and then just execute these queries with `GenericDao`?
Such approach would better decouple responsibilities and move business logic to concrete DAOs, i.e. `GenericDao` could be an abstract class with abstract `prepareQuery` metod, which currently is not fully generic.

Comment: @wypieprz I would like to be able to add clauses to the query that apply to every query built in every DAO, that's why I want to implement this in my `GenericDao`. If I do that in every class, I would have the same code for every query in every DAO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time, I decided I'm going to implement a different approach to this particular problem. Since I couldn't find any options on how to do this, I attempted to solve it on a JPA implementation level. Since I use Hibernate, I used [Hibernate filters](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html). For Eclipselink users: you can use Eclipselink's [Multi tenancy](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Development/Indigo/Multi-Tenancy) feature.

Unfortunately I haven't been able to find a solution on a higher level, so I still have to write a new implementation for this if I were to switch implementations. On the other hand, I probably won't switch to new implementations on a regular basis so that probably won't be an issue.